# How to connect the CPU fan on an ASRock X470 Taichi motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

I'm not sure how to connect the CPU fan to an ASRock X470 Taichi motherboard.

There are two cables with similar female sockets:

- Cable "1" comes from the CPU fan.
- Cable "2" comes from a small circuit board located behind the mainboard.

On the motherboard:

- socket "3" is labeled "CPU_FAN1"
- socket "4" is labeled "CPU_FAN2/WP".

Solved: see answer to my own question.

[image: ASRock X470 Taichi motherboard detail with CPU fan sockets and cables]

[image: Circuit board at the rear of ASRock X470 Taichi motherboard]

Comment: No clues in the motherboard manual?

Comment: Yes, the motherboard quick installation guide helped. There is also a second cable from the CPU fan. I connected it, but the fan is spinning no longer than half a second after starting the computer: https://superuser.com/questions/1421872/cpu-fan-not-spinning-after-powering-up-computer-is-it-normal

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misplaced the number 2 on the second picture. It looks like "cable 2" is connected to the CPU_FAN port on the "small circuit board" (look at the colors and the number of wires).

So you have to connect "cable 1" to the CPU_FAN1 port and "cable 2" to the CPU_FAN2 port on the mainboard. The small board is used to control the case fans and uses the PWM signal that the motherboard sends to the CPU fan. Instead of using the CPU_FAN2 port you could also use a case fan port on the mainboard if it supports PWM (4-pins).

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right. I corrected the second picture. And you're right, cable "1" goes to CPU_FAN1. Additionnally, there is one more cable to connect, as stated in the quick installation guide of the AsRock X470 Taichi (pages 25, 32 and 35).

Comment: You're welcome. Have you now been able to connect the fans properly?

Comment: Not sure as the fan only spins half a second when starting the computer. I connected the first cable from the CPU fan to CPU_FAN1 and the one from small circuit behind the motherboard to CPU_FAN2. The other cable from the CPU fan was connected according to the motherboard guide. More details here: https://superuser.com/questions/1421872/cpu-fan-not-spinning-after-powering-up-computer-is-it-normal

Answer (score 0):

The cable from the CPU fan (labeled "1" on the picture) goes to CPU_FAN1.
And the cable from the small circuit rear the mainboard (labeled "2" on the picture) goes to CPU_FAN2.

N.B. Additionally, the CPU fan may require connecting one more cable.
(eg. [How to wire AMD's AM4 Box Cooler SR3?](https://superuser.com/questions/1421872/how-to-wire-amds-am4-box-cooler-sr3))